# SIMILE Timeline Project Use For Commercial Project

Tags: plugins

Can we use [SIMILE](http://simile.mit.edu/) in Jira Plugin, which we will be selling?

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer: This is not legal advice, if you want to be sure contact a lawyer.**

I think so, reading the licence below you only need to supply the licence when using it.

> © Copyright The SIMILE Project
>   2003-2005.
>       Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
>   modification, are permitted provided
>   that the following conditions are met:
>
> 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright    notice,
>      this list of conditions and the
>      following disclaimer.
> 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
>      notice, this list of conditions and
>      the following disclaimer in the
>      documentation and/or other materials
>      provided with the distribution.
> 3. The name of the author may not be used to endorse or promote products
>      derived from this software without
>      specific prior written permission.
>
> THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE
>   AUTHOR ``AS IS'' AND ANY EXPRESS OR
>   IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
>   LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF
>   MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A
>   PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN
>   NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHOR BE LIABLE
>   FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
>   SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
>   DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED
>   TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR
>   SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
>   PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION)
>   HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
>   LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT
>   LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
>   NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN
>   ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
>   SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
>   POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.